# How to sort list using @IndexColumn annotation in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I sort an arrayList using @IndexColumn annotation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yes/no question are not appropriate for SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can not sort arrayList in hibernate using @indexColumn but its possible to use @OrderBy  or  @Sort(not applicable to list or arraylist).

using @OrderBy you can do like below where name should one of your Entity properties

Keep in mind that using javax.persistence.OrderBy allows us to specify the order of the collection via object properties, meanwhile org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy order a collection appending directly the fragment of SQL(not HQL) to order by clause.

```
@OrderBy("name")
 private List<Officer> officers = new ArrayList<Officer>();
```

If you need custom sorting then use set or sorted set instead of list and use sort annotation as shown below. here TimeComparator  is your custom comparator class

```
@Sort(type=SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator=TimeComparator.class)
```